# Best SharePoint Online Reference books

Tags: books, reference

Any recommendations for a SharePoint advanced or developer reference tome? Something more detailed and deeper than the very respected Dummy's books...

Comment: A little obsolete but very complete. https://zodml.org/sites/default/files/Microsoft_SharePoint_2013_Developer_Reference.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about any book for SharePoint Online development by Microsoft.

But you can find the detailed documentation SharePoint Online development from below links:

1. [SharePoint documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/).
2. [SharePoint development](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/).

You can get to know everything you need about SharePoint Online development from here.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, good bedtime reading

Comment: Welcome. Please vote and accept it as an answer if it helped you.